# How to fit a Tableau Dashboard to one page without scroll bars

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I need to have my dashboard to fit one page without a scroll bar.

I have tried putting the dashboard as Entire View and that works, but then it messes up when you try to filter something, it makes the rows look huge. I need to have it to Fit Width because of the filters.   I have it set up as custom size at 1500 X 1150. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: This might benefit from a picture of the dashboard in the states that you've tried. (Blurred where necessary.)

Comment: I got an answer, I changed the custom size to 1000X 1150. that worked and move headings over to show everything.

Comment: Good to hear! Best practice in that case is actually to answer your own question and apply the green check/tick. That way anyone who runs into the same issue in the future can see a quick answer.